# Unit testing a bash script manipulating the working directory path

Tags: unit-testing, bash, file-system

`bd` is a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script to conveniently jump multiple directory levels up from the current working directory instead of a tedious and possibly inaccurate `cd ../../../..`

Say, for example, that you are in the directory `/home/user/project/src/org/main` and you want to jump to `project`. Instead of counting the necessary levels to jump and typing `cd ../../..`, you can do `bd -s pro` (where `-s` is to match the start of the directory name, in this example "pro" for "project").

I came across this script in [another question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/65093/bd-a-quick-way-to-migrate-to-directories-up-in-the-hierarchy-using-batch-jav), and looking at the [github repository](https://github.com/vigneshwaranr/bd) I decided to jazz it up a little. But before going ahead and refactoring it, I wanted to make sure I'm not breaking anything, so I needed some sort of unit tests as a sane baseline first.

This is the main function in the `bd` script under testing,
and this is **not for code review**,
I'm including it here only for your reference in case it helps in some way:

```
# NOT for code review: the reference implementation under test
newpwd() {
  OLDPWD=$1
  if [ "$2" = "-s" ]
  then
    NEWPWD=`echo $OLDPWD | sed 's|\(.*/'$3'[^/]*/\).*|\1|'`
    index=`echo $NEWPWD | awk '{ print index($0,"/'$3'"); }'`
  elif [ "$2" = "-si" ]
  then
    NEWPWD=`echo $OLDPWD | sed 's|\(.*/'$3'[^/]*/\).*|\1|I'`
    index=`echo $NEWPWD | awk '{ print index(tolower($0),tolower("/'$3'")); }'`
  else
    NEWPWD=`echo $OLDPWD | sed 's|\(.*/'$2'/\).*|\1|'`
    index=`echo $NEWPWD | awk '{ print index($1,"/'$2'/"); }'`
  fi
}
```

What I'd like reviewed is my implementation of "unit tests" to verify the behavior of the `newpwd` function inside the `bd` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# loading the "newpwd" function from the bd script, a necessary ugliness for now
. bd nonexistent > /dev/null

success=0
failure=0
total=0

assertEquals() {
    ((total++))
    expected=$1
    actual=$2
    if [[ $expected = $actual ]]; then
        ((success++))
    else
        ((failure++))
        echo "Assertion failed: $expected != $actual" >&2
        caller 0
        echo
    fi
}

sample=/home/user/project/src/org/main/site/utils/file/reader/whatever

# test run with no args
newpwd $sample
assertEquals $sample $NEWPWD
assertEquals 0 $index

# test run with exact match
newpwd $sample src
assertEquals /home/user/project/src/ $NEWPWD
assertEquals 19 $index

# test run with prefix but no -s so not found
newpwd $sample sr
assertEquals $sample $NEWPWD
assertEquals 0 $index

# test run with prefix found
newpwd $sample -s sr
assertEquals /home/user/project/src/ $NEWPWD
assertEquals 19 $index

# test run with prefix not found because case sensitive
newpwd $sample -s Sr
assertEquals $sample $NEWPWD
assertEquals 0 $index

# test run with prefix found thanks to -si
newpwd $sample -si Sr
assertEquals /home/user/project/src/ $NEWPWD
assertEquals 19 $index

sample='/home/user/my project/src'

# test run with space in dirname
newpwd "$sample" -s my
assertEquals '/home/user/my project/' "$NEWPWD"
assertEquals 11 $index

red='\e[0;31m'
green='\e[0;32m'
nocolor='\e[0m'

echo
[[ $failure = 0 ]] && printf $green || printf $red
echo "Tests run: $total ($success success, $failure failed)"
printf $nocolor
echo
```

My questions:

- Is this easy to read? If not, how to improve it?
- Is this a good way to test stuff in Bash? Is there a better way? I'd rather not add external dependencies to the project though, I'm looking for something ultra-light, or a technique
- Are there any corner cases I missed?
- Any other improvement ideas?

Comment: You might want to take a look at bash_unit. Using a test framework would avoid to have to read and maintain test plumbery code. https://github.com/pgrange/bash_unit Regards,

Comment: @pgrange thanks for the tip, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just 2 cents:

1. I'd quote the right hand side of the `[[ ... = ... ]]` to avoid pattern interpretation. Cf.

   ```
   x=123
   y=*2*
   [[ $x =  $y  ]] && echo Equal without quotes
   [[ $x = "$y" ]] || echo Not equal with quotes
   ```
2. I like naming the tests. I'd probably add a third parameter to assertEquals and include it in the report. It also improves readability. Inspired by [Test::More](http://p3rl.org/Test::More) for Perl.

Comment: IIRC, you can avoid pattern interpretation by using double equals. However, I would still have quoted both sides of this test so that whitespace inside either expected or actual value doesn't break my tests. That said, I would have also used printf everywhere for consistency.

Comment: @mkalkov: I tried with double equals, the results are the same. Setting `x='1 2 3'` withough quoting left hand side doesn't change the results either. What were you trying to say?

Comment: I cannot test this until tomorrow, but I'm really surprised it worked with whitespaces, could be a [[ vs [ issue...

Comment: @mkalkov: Highly possible. That's why I used `[[`.

Comment: @malkov From the man page: "When  the == and != operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern" It explicitly states that `==` does pattern matching. (If anything, it leaves open the possibility that `=` is strictly for equality testing, but `=` and `==` behave identically inside `[[ ... ]]`.)